# How to use id, find an element and only return one field in Meteor + MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How to use id, find an element and only return one field in Meteor + MongoDB. I wanted to only return status but this doesnt work it return the whole docs? what am I missing?

```
stuCourse.classId = awquMqKMrYKqNueGx
stuCourse.courseId = m7pcWesZnhWxJgojG
```

client side

```
    const clas = Col_AllClasses.findOne({
        _id: stuCourse.classId,
        "courseList.courseId": stuCourse.courseId
    }, {
        field: {
            "courseList.status": 1
        }
    })
```

mongodb data

```
{
  "_id": "awquMqKMrYKqNueGx",
  "title": "haha1",
  "password": "123",
  "courseList": [
    {
      "courseId": "52Eo6XJ33CMGLo4rL",
      "status": 0
    },
    {
      "courseId": "m7pcWesZnhWxJgojG",
      "status": 0
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your are writing incorrect query related to what you wanted, you need to replace `field` keyword with `fields` then your Meteor mongo query will appear like

```
Col_AllClasses.findOne({
    _id: stuCourse.classId,
    "courseList.courseId": stuCourse.courseId
}, {
    fields: {
        "courseList.status": 1
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks i think it works but its still return 2 status instead of the one with the correct courseId. how do I just return one status with the matching courseId?

Answer (score 1):

```
field: {
        "courseList.status": 1
    }
```

should be

```
fields: {
        "courseList.status": 1
    }
```

Comment: thanks i think it works but its still return 2 status instead of the one with the correct courseId. how do I just return one status with the matching courseId?